# How can I customize the Ubuntu installer?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, custom-installer

I would like to know how can I customize the Ubuntu installer NOT customize Ubuntu, I just want to modify the installer.

Wanted to put the company logo on the installer.

Comment: Do you just want a different logo on the Live USB installer or do you want the logo on the installed system log in window?

Answer (score 3):

For your own use, it may be allowed. But Why?

You have to contact Canonical  for permission.

http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

http://www.canonical.com/intellectual-property-rights-policy

https://forms.canonical.com/trademark/

Making it easier to produce non-infringing derivatives

https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/technical-board/2015-November/002179.html

Rebranding

https://github.com/kamilion/customizer/wiki/Rebranding

Answer (score 0):

### A Different logo on the Live USB Installer

- Make a Persistent Live USB using mkusb in Ubuntu.
- Copy your logo to the target USB's **usbboot** partition.
- open the boot/grub folder and then open grub.cfg
- change "background_image /mkusb-grub-bg_800x600.png" to "background_image /[your logo's name].png
- save